# Shell variable - of limited size?

Tags: shell

Are shell variables limited in size? And which is the max size a variable can hold?

Comment: The answer would vary depending on what shell you are using, but if have to worry about the size of a shell variable, you probably should be using a more general purpose scripting language like Python or Ruby.

Comment: +1 Good suggestion, I think I'm writing an AWK script for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes they can be.  It depends on your OS and/or the shell flavours and versions.  It is safer to use temporary files if you expect variable values to exceed 1-4kB.

#### EDIT

Also see [What is the maximum size of an environment variable value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078031/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-environment-variable-value); this deals with the OS limitation on total `environ` size (cumulative size of all `VARIABLE=VALUE`s) which affects `export`ed variables, but the shell itself may have its own limitations re. all (including non-`export`ed) variable sizes.

This being said, unless you have portability in mind, GNU `bash` is relatively good about not limiting (non-`export`ed) variables' sizes and can very likely hold arbitrary amounts of data as long as `malloc` can find sufficient memory and contiguous address space. :)