# Concating string with shell script with accumulator

Tags: string, shell, accumulator

I'd like to convert a list separated with '\n' in another one separated with space.
Ex: 
Get a dictionary like ispell english dictionary. http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wordlist/ispell-enwl-3.1.20.zip

My initial idea was using a variable as accumulator:

```
a=""; cat american.0 | while read line; do a="$a $line"; done; echo $a
```

... but it results '\n' string!!!

Questions:

1. Why is it not working?
2. What is the correct way to do that?

   Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried: `cat american.0 | tr '\n' ' '`

Comment: Aside from the "useless use of `cat`" bit (`tr '\n' ' ' < american.0` would avoid that), how does `tr` not work?

Comment: I don't know. maybe the mac os X version of tr doesn't work properly. $tr '\n' ' ' < american.0 ... results: ' '$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you have a pipeline:

```
command_1 | command_2
```

each command is run in a separate subshell, with a separate copy of the parent environment. So any variables that the command creates, or any modifications it makes to existing variables, will not be perceived by the containing shell.

In your case, you don't really need the pipeline, because this:

```
cat filename | command
```

is equivalent, in every way that you need, to this:

```
command < filename
```

So you can write:

```
a=""; while read line; do a="$a $line"; done < american.0; echo $a
```

to avoid creating any subshells.

That said, according to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2451302/978917), you can't really rely on a shell variable being able to hold more than about 1–4KB of data, so you probably need to rethink your overall approach. Storing the entire word-list in a shell variable likely won't work, and even if it does, it likely won't work *well*.

---

**Edited to add:** To create a temporary file named `/tmp/american.tmp` that contains what the variable `$a` would have, you can write:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf %s " $line"
done < american.0 > /tmp/american.tmp
```

Comment: There's a problem in that line:

     -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

So, I rewrote that for:

     a=""; while IFS= read -r line; do a="$a $line"; echo $a; done < american.0; echo $a

But, the problem stills.

Comment: Thanx @ruakh. I am trying to use a temporary file.

a=""; while IFS= read -r line; do a="${line%\\n}"; echo $a >> /tmp/american.tmp; echo $a;done < american.0; echo $a.

But... the script doesn't remove the '\n' character.

Comment: @rdllopes: Re: the syntax error: Oops, interesting. I've fixed my answer. Re: your version with the temporary-file: The newlines are coming from `echo`. To disable them, use `echo -n`, or more portably, `printf %s`. (Also, most of that code is extraneous. You can just write `while IFS= read -r line; do printf %s " $line"; done < american.0 > /tmp/american.tmp`.)

Comment: Now I understood. I found an implicit problem here. iSpell files are Windows text (I didn't expected that). There's a 'Carrige Return' in every line. Using printf %s " $line" will return a blank file because every line overwrite previous one. That is the same problem why tr '\n' suggestion didn't work. Removing '\r', everything works fine. Thanx for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace '\n' with a space, you can simply use `tr` as follows:

```
a=$(tr '\n' ' ' < american.0)
```

Comment: works perfectly, removing before '\r' in american.0. Thanks. However, as @ruakh told me, there's a limit for variable size.