# BASH Script - Safe limits for string from command output

Tags: bash, svn, xargs

Good day,

I am writing a relatively simple BASH script that performs an SVN UP command, captures the console output, then does some post processing on the text.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# A script to alter SVN logs a bit

# Update and get output
echo "Waiting for update command to complete..."
TEST_TEXT=$(svn up --set-depth infinity)
echo "Done"

# Count number of lines in output and report it
NUM_LINES=$(echo $TEST_TEXT | grep -c '.*')
echo "Number of lines in output log: $NUM_LINES"

# Print out only lines containing Makefile
echo $TEST_TEXT | grep Makefile
```

This works as expected (ie: as commented in the code above), but I am concerned about what would happen if I ran this on a very large repository. Is there a limit on the maximum buffer size BASH can use to hold the output of a console command?

I have looked for similar questions, but nothing quite like what I'm searching for. I've read up on how certain scripts need to use the `xargs` in cases of large intermediate buffers, and I'm wondering if something similar applies here with respect to capturing console output.

eg:

```
# Might fail if we have a LOT of results
find -iname *.cpp | rm

# Shouldn't fail, regardless of number of results
find -iname *.cpp | xargs rm
```

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the maximum size of an environment variable value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078031/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-environment-variable-value)

Comment: Why don't you use `wc -l` instead of `grep -c '.*'`? Also, you should quote your variables: `echo "$TEST_TEXT"` in both places.

Comment: `find -iname *.cpp | rm` won't work because `rm` doesn't take files from stdin, but why do you think it "Might fail if we have a LOT of results"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using

```
var=$(hexdump /dev/urandom | tee out)
```

bash didn't complain; I killed it at a bit over 1G and 23.5M lines. You don't need to worry as long as your output fits in your system's memory.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason not to use a temporary file here.

```
tmp_file=$(mktemp XXXXX)

svn up --set-depth=infinity > $tmp_file
echo "Done"

# Count number of lines in output and report it
NUM_LINES=$(wc -l $tmp_file)
echo "Number of lines in output log: $NUM_LINES"

# Print out only lines containing Makefile
grep Makefile $tmp_file

rm $tmp_file
```

Comment: Fair enough. +1  I can't write to the filesystem (ro), which prevents me from doing this. However I didn't specify this in TFQ, and it's valid given the details I provided. Thanks!