# What is the maximum number of characters that the ksh variable accepts?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

I am trying to load  and parse a  really large text file. Although the loading is not a problem, but there are particular lines that have 2908778 characters on a single line.

This is causing an error in my script.

On the script below, I removed  all logic and just got straight to read line. 
I  also removed all valid lines and just left the really long line in one text file. When running I get the below error :

```
$ dowhiledebug.sh dump.txt
dowhiledebug.sh[6]: no space
Script Ended dump.txt
```

The actual script:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 filename=$1
 count=1
 if [ -f ${filename} ]; then
    echo "after then"
    while read line;
            do
            echo "$count"
            count=$((count+1))
            done < $filename
 else
    echo "Could not open file $filename"
 fi
 echo "Script Ended $filename"
```

Updated (2013-01-17)

Follow up question : [Is it possible to increase the maximum number of characters that ksh variable accepts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387344/is-it-possible-to-increase-the-maximum-number-of-characters-that-ksh-variable-ac)

Comment: Why not use `wc -l` to count the lines in the file?  It won't have the limits of the shell.  I guess the answer is "because I need to do other processing which I've removed for the reproduction".

Comment: On my Mac with `bash` 3.2, I created a file 4194304 characters and no newline at all, and then `bash` ignored the line altogether. I appended a single newline, and `bash` was quite happy to read the whole lot into memory.  So, your size is not a hard limit.  You'll need to look at how much memory there is on your system (more than 3 MiB, I'm sure), and whether the shell has many huge variables using up memory.

Comment: And, FWIW, the `sysconf` value for ARG_MAX on the machine is 256 KiB, just as in the answer.  I don't think the limit is directly related to ARG_MAX (though, I confess, I'm mildly surprised that I was able to echo a 4 MiB string to `wc`).  This is on the Mac, still.

Comment: what OS and version of ksh? Can you `echo ${.sh.version}` and get a value? If so, please include in your question above. Or could this be pdksh? Good luck to all.

Comment: @shelter AIX $ Version M-11/16/88f

Comment: Well don't do that then! Find some solution for your problem that doesn't require you to load the entire line into a ksh variable.

Comment: @user1985725 : `ver 88/f` That's part of your problem. See if you SysAdmin can point you to a newer version. If you're running on AIX, you're likely not in an environment where you can have someone build a one-off with larger ARG_MAX. It's likely time to consider another language, or analyse your processing to find another solution. Good luck.

Comment: I would use `python` or some other scripting language for that purpose.

Comment: [What is the maximum size of an environment variable value?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1078031/995714)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The reason you were able to `echo` such a large string is that `echo` is a _builtin_ in Bash, in which case ARG_MAX doesn't apply. Compare `echo "$(awk 'BEGIN { while (c++ < '"$(( $(getconf ARG_MAX) + 1 ))"') printf "=" }')"` to `/bin/echo "$(awk 'BEGIN { while (c++ < '"$(( $(getconf ARG_MAX) + 1 ))"') printf "=" }')"`. That said, I too think that ARG_MAX is not relevant to the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit for any shell is the limit of the C command line maximum. Here's a little program that pulls the information out of `/usr/include/limits.h` for you:

```
cpp <<HERE | tail -1
#include <limits.h>
ARG_MAX
HERE
```

Mine gives me (256 * 1024) or 262144 characters.

Doesn't work if the C compiler isn't installed, but it's probably a similar limit.

Comment: While it's good to know the max. length of a command line when invoking an external utility (which can more easily be obtained with `getconf ARG_MAX`), this limit does _not_ apply here, because the data is read from a file, not passed on the command line; also, `read` is a shell builtin, not an external utility.
The following `ksh` command reads a line that is 1 byte larger than `getconf ARG_MAX`, which succeeds: `read line < <(awk 'BEGIN { while (c++ < '"$(( $(getconf ARG_MAX) + 1 ))"') printf "=" }'); echo "${#line}"`.

Answer (score 6):

what OS and version of ksh? Can you `echo ${.sh.version}` and get a value? If so, please include in your question above. Or could this be pdksh?

Here's a test that will get you in the ballpark, assuming a modern ksh supporting `(( i++ ))` math evaluations:

```
#100 char var
var=1234578901234456789012345678901234567890123456789012345789012344567890123456789012345678901234567890

$ while (( i++ < 10000 )) ;do  var="$var$var" ; print "i=$i\t" ${#var} ; done
i=1      200
i=2      400
i=3      800
i=4      1600
i=5      3200
i=6      6400
i=7      12800
i=8      25600
i=9      51200
i=10     102400
i=11     204800
i=12     409600
i=13     819200
i=14     1638400
i=15     3276800
i=16     6553600
i=17     13107200
i=18     26214400
i=19     52428800
i=20     104857600
i=21     209715200
i=22     419430400
-ksh: out of memory

$ print -- ${.sh.version}
Version JM 93t+ 2010-05-24
```

AND that is just the overall size of the environment that can be supported. When dealing with the command-line environment and "words" after the program name, there is a limit to the number of words, regardless of overall size.

Some shells man page will have a section LIMITS that may show something like `max-bytes 200MB, max-args 2048`. This information may be in a different section, it will definitely have different labels and different values I have included, OR it may not be there at all, hence the above code loop, so look carefully around and if you find a source for this info, either add an answer to this Q, or update this one.

The `bash 4.4` std man page doesn't seem to have this information and its harder to find a `ksh` doc all the time. Check your `man ksh` and hope that you can find a documented limit.

IHTH

Comment: Hi shelter, assuming that there is a limit. Is there a way to extend t this limit? Because I'm sure that the records I'm loading does not stop at 2M characters per line? Is there an alternative to "while read line"?