# Is it possible to increase the maximum number of characters that ksh variable accepts?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ksh

This is a follow up question to

[What is the maximum number of characters that the ksh variable accepts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371326/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-characters-that-the-ksh-variable-accepts)

I checked my environment and it's allowing only

```
#include <sys/limits.h>
$ cpp <<  HERE | tail -1
> #include <limits.h>
> ARG_MAX
> HERE
1048576
```

Is there a way to increase this? Or any alternatives for

```
 while read line;
   do
      #parse logic
   done < $filename
```

To handle really long lines? Based from the records I'm parsing it will not stop at 2M character lines.

Environment Details :

```
 AIX $ KSH Version M-11/16/88f
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want so big shell variables?

Comment: And is it an AIX kernel, or a Linux one?

Comment: Can't you parse your file in something else than `ksh`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could compile a Linux 3.7.x kernel, and edit its `include/uapi/linux/limits.h` file to increase the `ARG_MAX`  argument (to some bigger power of two, e.g. 2097152). But you should rather have a lot of RAM (e.g. 8GBytes) if you want to increase it more.

The actual limit is related to [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html). That man page has a paragraph on it.

But you could probably avoid having huge shell variables (in the Unix environment). Did you consider using some other tool (`awk`, `python`, `perl` ....) to read your file? Their variable environment is not the shell environment transmitted to forked programs, so they can have variables with very long values. Maybe `ksh` has some builtin (`unexport`) to avoid exporting some variable into the Unix environment.

Comment: Hi Basile, thanks for your response. I don't have  liberty to recompile the kernel. One question, does this apply to all scripting languages? If I use perl will I also encounter this when doing a read line?

Comment: I am parsing a large file and some  lines have that many records. The script is working 99% of the time, but for 1% of the records it has 2M+ characters per line.

Comment: `ARG_MAX` doesn't come into play here, because it limits the length of the command line when invoking _external utilities_, whereas `read` is a shell _builtin_ (and the data is read from a file, not passed as a command-line argument). The following `ksh` command demonstrates that it is possible to read lines that are longer than `ARG_MAX`: `IFS= read line < <(printf "%$(( $(getconf ARG_MAX) + 1 ))s"); echo "${#line}"`