# Why is xargs not replacing the second {}

Tags: xargs

I'm using xargs to try to echo the name of a file, followed by its contents.  Here is the command

`find output/ -type f | xargs -I {} sh -c "echo {} ; cat {}"`

However for some reason, the second replace after `cat` is not being replaced.  Only for *some* files, so some files do work correctly.

To be clear, I'm not looking for a command that lets me echo the name of a file followed by its contents, I'm trying to understand why this specific command does not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224777/xargs-command-length-limits/45595216#45595216 for linking

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Turns out that the command was too long, so it was working with shorter file names and failing for longer ones.  From `man xargs`

```
-I replstr
             Execute utility for each input line, replacing one or more occurrences of replstr in up to replacements (or 5 if no -R flag is specified) arguments to utility with the
             entire line of input.  The resulting arguments, after replacement is done, will not be allowed to grow beyond 255 bytes; this is implemented by concatenating as much
             of the argument containing replstr as possible, to the constructed arguments to utility, up to 255 bytes.  The 255 byte limit does not apply to arguments to utility
             which do not contain replstr, and furthermore, no replacement will be done on utility itself.  Implies -x.
```

Comment: Also from the manpages:

-S replsize
             Specify the amount of space (in bytes) that -I can use for replacements.  The default for replsize is
             255.

I was able to use xargs with a long command by specifying `xargs -S 100000 -I {} <rest of command>`.

Comment: I dug into this more and learned that I didn't run into a command length issue when running on Linux, only mac os. The manpages I mentioned above are from mac os.

Answer (score 4):

The root cause of the problem is pointed out in [Carlos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45595116/1043209), but without a solution.

After some googling, I couldn't find a way to lift up the 255 characters limit.

So a probable way to workaround it, is to use shell variable as a substitution.

Example:

```
find . | xargs -I% sh -c 'F="%";iconv -f gb2312 -t utf-8 "$F">"$F.out";mv "$F.out" "$F"'
```

Remember to use **single quotes** at the outermost `sh -c` parameter string, we don't want the `$F` inside to be replaced by our parent shell.

Comment: you can escape the $ in front of a variable to make the subshell fill it instead of the parent shell if you have to use double quotes

Answer (score 2):

Is it files with white space in the name that create problems? Try adding \", like this:

```
find output/ -type f | xargs -I {} sh -c "echo \"{}\" ; cat \"{}\""
```

This worked for me using Bash.

Comment: Good idea, but there are not spaces in my case

Comment: This should be a comment. You should first ask for details if needed. Please read this: [answer]

Comment: Assuming you're using Bash, if you use `set -x` and then run your command, what is the output for a file name that does not work?