# How can I execute each line of a file using xargs and GNU bash 5.2.0(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin21.6.0)?

Tags: bash, macos, xargs

I have a txt file, each line is a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) command. I would like to execute each. I do this on Ubuntu:

```
cat file_with_commands.txt | xargs -P10 -I {} bash -c '{}'
```

and it works. The `-P10` flag makes sure up to 10 processes can be run at once. The same on Mac results in:

```
bash: line 1: {}: command not found
bash: line 1: {}: command not found
bash: line 1: {}: command not found
bash: line 1: {}: command not found
bash: line 1: {}: command not found
bash: line 1: {}: command not found
```

`bash --version` tells me: `GNU bash, version 5.2.0(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin21.6.0)`. The same in Ubuntu gives: `GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

How can I execute each line of `file_with_commands.txt` on Mac?

I also tried `cat file_with_commands.txt | xargs -P10 -I {} bash -c "{}"` and `cat file_with_commands.txt | xargs -P10 -I {} bash -c {}`, results are the same.

On Mac, `xargs --version` gives:

```
xargs: illegal option -- -
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements] [-S replsize]]
             [-J replstr] [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs]
             [-s size] [utility [argument ...]]
```

`cat file_with_commands.txt | xargs -t -P 10 -I {} bash -c '{}'` gives:

```
bash -c {}
bash -c {}
bash -c {}
bash -c {}
bash -c {}
bash -c {}
bash: line 1: {}: command not found
bash: line 1: {}: command not found
bash: line 1: {}: command not found
bash: line 1: {}: command not found
bash: line 1: {}: command not found
bash: line 1: {}: command not found
```

`cat file_with_commands.txt | xargs -t -I {} echo {}` returns:

```
echo {}
{}
echo {}
{}
echo {}
{}
echo {}
{}
echo {}
{}
echo {}
{}
```

Interestingly, this weird behaviour is only present if the line is long. If the line is short enough, I get the line itself when `echo`ing it, not `{}`. 254 character long strings seem to be short enough, longer ones seem to be too long.

Comment: but.... why not just `bash file_with_commands.txt`? `bash: line 1: {}: command not found` Are you 100% sure, that you typed `-I {}` and not `-I ﹛ ﹜`  and not `-I ｛ ｝` or anything else?

Comment: Then post real world use case. What is the output of `xargs --version`? What does `xargs -t ....` output?

Comment: Question appended with these details!

Comment: `xargs -t .... does not output anything within a minute of trying.` Sorry, I meant, `cat file_with_commands.txt | xargs -t -P 10 -I {} bash -c '{}'`

Comment: Updated! I didn't know about the -t option, but it seems like a good way to locate the problem a bit more. It seems like bash is not getting the command it is supposed to execute from xargs.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224777/xargs-command-length-limits.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958689/running-multiple-commands-with-xargs has some variations, though it's about a different problem.