# How to process null-separated content at the shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

After answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35615581/how-to-delete-x-number-of-files-in-a-directory/35615645), I am now wondering the best way to further process the null-separated output of `find -print0`.

The following command would search for a phrase in the first 10 files that find returns - maybe we don't want to search too many at one time.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 | head -10 | xargs grep "Specific Phrase"
```

However, if there are newlines or spaces in the filenames, this can become a challenge as they will mess up our `xargs` command.

How could I write the following so it works - can I do this in bash or do I need to use a tool like `awk` to break this string up at the nulls?

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | head -10 | xargs -0 grep "Specific Phrase"
```

It seems the other words I could use to describe this is how to change the field separator to be a null character.

Comment: **Which** shell? The facilities for this are far better in bash or ksh than POSIX sh.

Comment: I realized I didn't know how to do it in any shell. Lets say `bash` as it is very common.

Comment: That was kind of a "leading comment", as the *solution* @CharlesDuffy provided below is implemented in bash, but the question mentioned only tools that are external to most shells. I would love to see a Charles-approved shell-agnostic answer to this question, or at least one that works in a POSIX shell.

Comment: I posted an `awk` answer below as well that does not require complex shell machinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, you could do something like the following:

```
head0() {
  local item i=0
  while IFS= read -r -d '' item && (( ++i <= "$1" )); do
    printf '%s\0' "$item"
  done
}

find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | head0 10 | xargs -0 grep "Specific Phrase"
```

The relevant idioms here are `IFS= read -r -d '' item` to read, and `printf '%s\0' "$item"` to write.

To explain that `read` command in detail:

- `IFS=` prevents whitespace from being trimmed from either the beginning or end of any string
- `read -r` prevents literal backslashes from being consumed or suppressed.
- `-d ''` sets the first character of the string `''` -- an empty NUL-delimited string, of which the first character is thus NUL -- as the character which will terminate the read.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another possible option using `awk`, which was presented as part of an answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35615581/how-to-delete-x-number-of-files-in-a-directory) but is also applicable here.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 \
    | awk 'NR<=10;NR>10{exit}' RS="\0" ORS="\0" \
    | xargs -0 grep "Specific Phrase"
```