# How to access Google service account credentials in Docker

Tags: docker, rust, discord

I have developed a Discord bot that I would like to push to AWS for a more persistent service than when running on my machine.

That bot uses Google Service Account to access Google spreadsheet data that is currently sitting on my machine as a JSON file.

What's the most secure way to package this as a Docker component (or more generally to move that to some AWS server if using Docker is not the best way to approach this)?

I understand that for most credentials it's best to use environment variables. That would work for the Discord bot credentials but not for Google's which are too verbose.

The bot is developed in Rust.

Comment: It's not a "dummy" question, but it is *off-topic* for Stack Overflow. Asking for "the best" solution is going to be opinion-based 99.9999% of the time, and that's assuming that there's even a single "best" answer to start with. For example, there's no "best" way to sort an array.

Comment: Fair push. Would it be better/ok to ask for a way to do it then @Shepmaster?

Comment: You already know how to do it, you've listed two possible ways (environment variable, JSON file). It seems like [environment variables can easily be 4 MB, maybe up to 100's of MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078031/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-environment-variable-value), so saying it's "too verbose" seems misleading or incorrect.